# Process to upload a Spring Social module to a public Maven repository

Tags: spring, maven, spring-social

We've developed [a Spring Social ORCID module on GitHub](https://github.com/yucigou/spring-social-orcid), as an extension to Spring Social that enables integration with [ORCID](http://orcid.org/). I've also added it to [the Spring Social API providers' list](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/Api-Providers).

Wonder if possible to upload the artifact to a public Maven repository, such as https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-orcid, similar to Spring Social Facebook:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook?

My concern is that as this Spring Social ORCID module is so far my personal project, wonder if I could use the Maven groupID

> org.springframework.social

before someone from the Spring Social project has approved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: Reply from sonatype.org

Artifacts under the groupId `org.springframework` must be explicitly approved by representatives of Pivotal.  If you wish to publish your artifacts to Maven Central without their approval, you'll have to choose a different groupId.